Having Trouble Merging my CSS file to my JavaFX File, A couple problems
I am asking for help because I have tried multiple ways to try and get my css file to merge with my JavaFX File, I believe I'm doing it correctly but may be using incorrect syntax in the css or maybe just the wrong functions altogether.
File Format:
JavaFX File is in src/main/java/com/circles
CSS File is in src/main/java/resources/styleSheet.css
Expected Results:
Create A JavaFX Border that holds four circles, the first two being white, and the second two being green and red. The first circle will have two vertical lines next to the left and the right of the circle.
Error:
It's an error on my end and not the IDE, since I am currently being shown an output that only shows three black circles with two very small black lines to my first circle is missing a circle, instead of my expected results.
Any help would be amazing, I will post the code below and I have a couple different examples in that code of how I had tried to get it to work, instead of using the same method for all of them.
package com.example.circles;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class circles extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Pane to hold the shapes

        Pane pane = new Pane();

        // Rectangle Black stroke with transparent fill

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(50, 50, 700, 400);

        rectangle.getStyleClass().add("border");

        // Circle 1: White fill, black stroke
        Circle circle1 = new Circle(100, 150, 50);
        circle1.setId("white-circle");

        // Circle 2: White fill, black stroke
        Circle circle2 = new Circle(250, 150, 50);
        circle2.setId("white-circle");

        // Circle 3: Red fill
        Circle circle3 = new Circle(400, 150, 50);
        circle3.getStyleClass().add("red-circle");

        // Circle 4: Green fill
        Circle circle4 = new Circle(550, 150, 50);
        circle4.getStyleClass().add("green-circle");

        // Vertical line to the left of Circle 1
        Line leftLine = new Line(50, 100, 50, 200); // x = 50, y1 = 100, y2 = 200
        leftLine.setStrokeWidth(2);
        leftLine.setStyle("-fx-stroke: black;");

        // Vertical line to the right of Circle 1
        Line rightLine = new Line(150, 100, 150, 200); // x = 150, y1 = 100, y2 = 200
        rightLine.setStrokeWidth(2);
        rightLine.setStyle("-fx-stroke: black;");


        // Add all shapes to the pane
        pane.getChildren().addAll(leftLine, rightLine, circle1, circle2, circle3, circle4);


        // Create the scene and link the CSS file
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("styleSheet.css");


        // Set up the stage
        primaryStage.setTitle("Circles");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }
}

CSS File
/* Rectangle border style */
#border-rectangle {
    -fx-fill: transparent;
    -fx-stroke: black;
    -fx-stroke-width: 2;
}

/* First circle style */
#circle1 {
    -fx-fill: white;
    -fx-stroke: black;
    -fx-stroke-width: 2;
}

/* Second circle style */
#circle2 {
    -fx-fill: white;
    -fx-stroke: black;
    -fx-stroke-width: 2;
}

/* Third circle style */
#circle3 {
    -fx-fill: red;
}

/* Fourth circle style */
#circle4 {
    -fx-fill: green;
}

/* Vertical line style */
#vertical-line {
    -fx-stroke: black;
    -fx-stroke-width: 2;
}


There are multiple problems (some will break stuff, some are just conventions):

Your class is in the com directory "src>main>java>com>circles", but your CSS is not.
Using com is not a good idea.
Your package name is com.example.circles but it doesn't match the directory you store the java file under: "src>main>java>com>circles".
Class names should follow naming conventions.
CSS is a resource and should not be under the java directory. Follow the maven standard directory layout (even if you don't use maven).
CSS style classes need to be defined with . instead of #.
The javafx.controls module includes the default modena.css stylesheet, so, when using CSS it is best to add that module to the module graph.
If using a CSS file it is often not a good practice to also add inline styles (I realize you probably just did that to demo what you tried).
The style class and id names you use in code need to match the values in your CSS file (yours do not).
You aren't adding all objects to the scene, if the object isn't in the scene, you can't see it.
You are trying to size the scene smaller than the objects in the scene.
Some of your shapes draw over some of your other shapes so you can't see them.

Example
So following that advice, you can get the following output:

With this example code.
src/main/java/module-info.java
module org.example.cicles {
    requires javafx.controls;
    exports org.example.circles;
}

src/main/java/org/example/circles/CircleApp.java
package org.example.circles;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Objects;

public class CircleApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Pane to hold the shapes
        Pane pane = new Pane();

        // Rectangle Black stroke with transparent fill
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(25, 25, 600, 250);
        rectangle.setId("border-rectangle");

        // Circle 1: White fill, black stroke
        Circle circle1 = new Circle(100, 150, 50);
        circle1.setId("circle1");

        // Circle 2: White fill, black stroke
        Circle circle2 = new Circle(250, 150, 50);
        circle2.setId("circle2");

        // Circle 3: Red fill
        Circle circle3 = new Circle(400, 150, 50);
        circle3.setId("circle3");

        // Circle 4: Green fill
        Circle circle4 = new Circle(550, 150, 50);
        circle4.setId("circle4");

        // Vertical line to the left of Circle 1
        Line leftLine = new Line(50, 100, 50, 200); // x = 50, y1 = 100, y2 = 200
        leftLine.setId("vertical-line");

        // Vertical line to the right of Circle 1
        Line rightLine = new Line(150, 100, 150, 200); // x = 150, y1 = 100, y2 = 200
        rightLine.setId("vertical-line");


        // Add all shapes to the pane
        pane.getChildren().addAll(rectangle, leftLine, rightLine, circle1, circle2, circle3, circle4);


        // Create the scene and link the CSS file
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 650, 300);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(
                Objects.requireNonNull(
                        CircleApp.class.getResource(
                                "style-sheet.css"
                        )
                ).toExternalForm()
        );


        // Set up the stage
        primaryStage.setTitle("Circles");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

src/main/resources/org/example/circles/style-sheet.css
/* Rectangle border style */
#border-rectangle {
    -fx-fill: transparent;
    -fx-stroke: black;
    -fx-stroke-width: 2;
}

/* First circle style */
#circle1 {
    -fx-fill: white;
    -fx-stroke: black;
    -fx-stroke-width: 2;
}

/* Second circle style */
#circle2 {
    -fx-fill: white;
    -fx-stroke: black;
    -fx-stroke-width: 2;
}

/* Third circle style */
#circle3 {
    -fx-fill: red;
}

/* Fourth circle style */
#circle4 {
    -fx-fill: green;
}

/* Vertical line style */
#vertical-line {
    -fx-stroke: black;
    -fx-stroke-width: 2;
}

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.circles</groupId>
    <artifactId>circle-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>circle-demo</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <javafx.version>23.0.1</javafx.version>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

Related
Further info on finding resources (do study it):

How do I determine the correct path for FXML files, CSS files, Images, and other resources needed by my JavaFX Application?

Unrelated Advice
Use a build system
Use Maven or Gradle (Maven may be easier to get started with if you have used neither one).  Those build systems will automatically handle building code following the standard directory layout and can interface with your IDE.
Understand package naming conventions
Short note on package naming conventions.
It would be best to use your own namespace such as org.myname.examples or something generic like org.example and place everything in that.
Using org.example makes it clear you never to intend to publish the code to a central shared repository, and using your own namespace means you could publish to a central shared repository.  But for code not published to a repository, it doesn't matter too much.

Thank you so much, you have given me an excellent beginning to much research I am going to start reading asap and you have also helped my understanding where to package my project and why, you are amazing!
